# Compiling nginx with ngx_pagespeed

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed, page-speed

I have build nginx with ngx_pagespeed module. Do I still need to keep the original ngx_pagespeed directory?

When I use the compiled binary across multiple servers with mod_pagespeed on, I am getting no response.

Comment: Have you checked the setting in your other servers? Do they have pagespeed enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with nginx-1.9.9 and ngx_pagespeed 1.10.33.2. It stopped responding after working for some time after service start. I suggest you recompile nginx with pagespeed version [1.9.32.10-beta](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/releases/tag/v1.9.32.10-beta) for now. I guess 1.10.* is considered somewhat unstable, since it's not listed as "Latest release" on [github](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/releases).